# Is adding 'Z' at the end of timezone mandatory for UTC

Tags: datetime, utc

If a system says they are sending datetime in UTC, is it mandatory for them to either add "Z" at the end or specify the offset with "+" or "-" hours at the end?

For example, is it valid if datetime is specified as this `"2014-10-23T10:00:00"` (without `Z` or without + or - timezone)?

As per XSD datetime: it is valid, I am confused. If it is valid, does it mean it is the localtime and is it daylight saving adjusted?

Comment: It's all covered in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: "in UTC format" - there is no such thing as "UTC format". UTC is just a time-zone.

Comment: "If it is valid does it means its the localtime and is it daylight saving adjusted?" - I believe XSD leaves that up to the application. (Note that UTC does not have daylight savings, so that point is moot).

Comment: Thanks Dai..Can you please clarify, is it mandatory to set Z at the end if the data is in UTC

Comment: You really need to be a little more specific. Valid according to what? In some contexts it is valid in others no. You basically answered your own question when you (correctly) state that it is valid in XSD.

Comment: _If a system says they are sending datetime in UTC,_ The standard way for a system to say it's sending time in UTC is to put a Z on the end. You can do this any way you like but why would you not follow ISO8601 to the letter? Why invent a different proprietary way to indicate UTC time?

Comment: yes, i understand that. The sending system needs to put a Z at the end so that the application which has received it knows that it is in UTC. In  the case where there is no z specified at the end and also there is no ( + or - offset specified) will it be up to the receiving application to interpret it ? Does the receiver treats it as local timezone ?

Comment: If the time has no time offset, you may not known what kind of time you are dealing. Is it local time, is it UTC, etc. Protocols may specify it, but all programmers know exactly what such time means. `Z` is just a shortcut of `+00:00` (military Zulu time, but do not use other military letter times!). UTC has no summer time, just eventually leap seconds. But usually if you need to add the `Z`, it means that something wrong was decided upstream (and good luck to find if it was UTC, summer time corrected, etc.). Time offset is a good way to document what time you are dealing.

Comment: _Does the receiver treats it as local timezone_ it depends on... what the recieving system is an how it works.

Answer (score 1):

I will address the question more or less in reverse order. "As per XSD datetime: it is valid, i am confused. If it is valid does it means its the localtime and is it daylight saving adjusted?"

According to [*XML Schema Part 2: Datatypes Second Edition*](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime) (28 October 2004) '"Local" or untimezoned times are presumed to be the time in the timezone of some unspecified locality as prescribed by the appropriate legal authority'. I would interpret this to mean that in the absence of characters in the datetime indicating the time zone, the time zone must be discovered from context or agreement among the communicating parties. If you are able create such an agreement, or provide appropriate context, you could use a string with no timezone characters to represent UTC.

As stated in a comment by @Dai UTC may be represented in any format, such as "thirteen hours fifty-eight minutes Coordinated Universal Time".

Comment: Thank you. The agreement here was for the sender to send time in utc timezone and iso format. Considering that if they are not sending z at the end, is it fair to say that it is incorrect and they  should send z? Not sure why xml specification didnt enforce timezone as must for datetime datatype. Would have been more clear and less ambiguity if they would have enforced it rather than making it as an thing optional in the specification.

Comment: If there is an agreement that the local time for a certain data transmission is UTC, then there is no requirement to add a timezone to the XSD datetime. Of course, if the data being transmitted isn't in XML format, the whole XSD scheme doesn't apply and there are no rules. Apart from UTC, a possible reason to give a local time is to require that a future even occur at a certain local time, no matter what timezone changes make between when the time is written and when the event occurs.